# Strawberry perl on windows 10 does not find modules in current directory

Tags: perl, windows-10, strawberry-perl

I've installed Strawberry Perl v5.28.0 MSWin32-x64-multi-thread on windows 10. However, I noticed that it does not find module under the current directory and every time I run any script, I've to add current directory into the path.

```
perl -I . somescript.pl
```

This was not the case earlier. Is there a way to put the current directory in the path by default so I don't have to run with

```
perl -I .
```

**Note:** While browsing, I read somewhere(can't remember the link or website) that latest versions of Perl excluded a current directory from @INC for security reasons. But I'm trying to find a solution for a development machine.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to look in the current work directory. It often makes sense for a script to look for modules bundled with it, which is to say it sometimes makes sense to tell Perl to look for modules in a path relative to the location of the script. To that end, the script should include

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

use lib $RealBin;   # or "$RealBin/lib" or "$RealBin/../lib", etc
```

If this is only for development, setting env var `PERL5LIB` might make more sense.